# How to Convert Time Format DayOfyear:Hour:Minute.000

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, type-conversion

I want to plot data where Y is some position and X is time. The time is in the format `240:19:35:50.000` (Julian:Hour:Minute:Second.Milliseconds). When I try to plot it outputs the error `ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "240:19:35:50.000" at position 3`

I have tried using string formatters such as strftime but had no success wiith:

```
time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
```

here is a snippet of my code:

```
# I have no need for the julian portion I removed it
time = data['Time'].str.slice(start=4)
time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
pitchPlot = plt.subplot(7, 1, 3)
plt.plot((time), data['Pitch Stick Position(IN)'])
```

This outputs: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime' which is odd because it shows in [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) it exists.

What I would like is to convert this to H:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds as a datetime object so I can plot it using matplotlib.

Update: I tried using to_datetime as suggested with

```
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3].dt.time
```

but the output is strange. Here are the last 6 original inputs

```
index    time
10165    240:19:35:49.000
10166    240:19:35:49.200
10167    240:19:35:49.400
10168    240:19:35:49.600
10169    240:19:35:49.800
10170    240:19:35:50.000
```

and the last 6 outputs:

```
index    time converted
10165    19:35:49
10166    19:35:49.200000
10167    19:35:49.400000
10168    NaN
10169    NaN
10170    NaN
```

Comment: The link suggests `Series.dt.strftime`, not `Series.strftime`. But I doubt that is of use if you have a string already. So what about `pandas.to_datetime()`?

Comment: Good suggestion. I got it working with `data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3].dt.time` but theres sometimes weird formatting.. Ill put date the output with an image in the original post.

Comment: any idea why there are NaN values?

Comment: What do you need the `[:-3].dt.time` for at the end? Does it change anything when you leave that out?

Comment: It originally complained about the string format not matching. Removing the [:-3] fixes the NaN. Looks like it was removing the minute values when times were `19:02:01` making the time  invalid for the string formatter. Many thanks!